# What is the proper Maven repository for Apache Karaf 2.2.10?

Tags: maven, apache-karaf

I'm upgrading my build from `Karaf` `2.2.2` to `2.2.10` and have a problem finding one artifact:

```
Can't resolve bundle org.apache.karaf:org.apache.karaf.management:jar:2.2.10: 
Failure to find org.apache.karaf:org.apache.karaf.management:jar:2.2.10
in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central
has elapsed or updates are forced
```

This is declared in `karaf-standard-features.xml` of `Karaf` `2.2.10` tarball in `karaf-framework` feature:

```
<bundle>mvn:org.apache.karaf/org.apache.karaf.management/2.2.10</bundle>
```

I've noticed that this artifact is not present in main Maven repo:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.karaf/org.apache.karaf.management

But I have no idea where else would I find it?

Please point me to a proper Maven repo for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that group id and artifact id have been changed (see [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.karaf.management/org.apache.karaf.management.server/2.2.10)):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.karaf.management</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.karaf.management.server</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>
```